# unable to start jboss Host Controller within docker

Tags: docker, jboss, centos

```
domain controller on centos <-- host machine
host controller on centos   <-- docker
```

I have installed jboss on centos docker image and tried to start standalone server which starts with out any issues. However, when I want to start the slave and sync it with domain I get error as below:

```
15:57:18,045 DEBUG [org.jboss.modules] (Controller Boot Thread) Module org.jboss.as.cli:main defined by local module loader @26538d04 (finder: local module finder @374f1544 (roots: /opt/jboss-eap-6.2/modules,/opt/jboss-eap-6.2/modules/system/layers/base))
15:57:23,477 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.host.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) failed to connect to 10.10.10.10:9999: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://10.10.10.10:9999. The connection timed out
      at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionUtils.connectSync(ProtocolConnectionUtils.java:131) [jboss-as-protocol-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnection.openConnection(RemoteDomainConnection.java:198) [jboss-as-host-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnection$InitialConnectTask.connect(RemoteDomainConnection.java:560) [jboss-as-host-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at org.jboss.as.protocol.ProtocolConnectionManager.connect(ProtocolConnectionManager.java:70) [jboss-as-protocol-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnection.connect(RemoteDomainConnection.java:136) [jboss-as-host-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at org.jboss.as.host.controller.RemoteDomainConnectionService.register(RemoteDomainConnectionService.java:194) [jboss-as-host-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at org.jboss.as.host.controller.DomainModelControllerService.connectToDomainMaster(DomainModelControllerService.java:577) [jboss-as-host-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at org.jboss.as.host.controller.DomainModelControllerService.boot(DomainModelControllerService.java:438) [jboss-as-host-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:253) [jboss-as-controller-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
```

---

The way I am starting my container is as follows:

```
docker run -p 18080:808 -p 19990:9990 -it jboss_test
```

I am able to ping the container and from docker container to host.

However, when I try to start the web server in docker with a port say 80 i get connection refused while doing wget from host

wget http://10.10.10.20:80 <-- give connection refused from host. Is there something that I might be missing in docker network?

Comment: Maybe you have another application running on that port?

Comment: Have you tried to see the Docker logs? maybe it might give you a clue? also you are starting it like: docker run -p 80:808 -p 81:9990 ?

Comment: @Sergiu no i gave an example like docker run -p 18080:808 -p 19990:9990 -it jboss_test. no other port is using it. i did netstat before starting the server.  some thing do with docker network , missing something.

Comment: Why is the docker connecting to `10.10.10.10:9999`? What is your Host IP?

Comment: host ip is 10.10.10.10 and application port is 9999 to which jboss is connecting.(from docker container)